# First Order Theory with Linear Ordering

Tags: first-order-logic, formal-languages, decidability

(*Updated*) I am trying to solve the following problem, any help would be much appreciated!

Let Γ be the theory in the language containing just the binary relational symbol ≤, and Γ says
``the relation ≤ is a linear ordering, and every element has an immediate successor in ≤’’.

(a) Write Γ down precisely in the language of first order logic.

(b) Show that there is a sentence in the language, which cannot be decided from the axioms of Γ.

This is what I have so far:

a) Γ  =  { ∀x ∀y ∀z ((x ≤ y ∧ y ≤ z) → x ≤ z), ∀x (x ≤ x), ∀x ∀y ((x ≤ y ∧ y ≤ x) → x = y), ∀x ∀y (x ≤ y ∨ y ≤ x), ∀x ∃y ∀z (x ≤ z → (y ≤ z ∧ x ≤ y)}

I think this is correct.

b) I am a little confused on (b). What I am thinking is, I just need to show there exists a sentence which is undecidable. So, based on the hint from Max(Thank you.), I came up with the following sentence:

∀x ∃y ∀z (z ≤ x → (z ≤ y ∧ y ≤ x) .

This is undecidable, because there is no sentence in Γ which proves this sentence.

Comment: The first question should be easy for you to solve (if not, what trouble do you have with it ?); and for the second one the hint I would give is : we know there are successors, but what about predecessors ?

Comment: @NoahSchweber I posted an edit with what I've tried.

Comment: @Max I tried making a sentence about the existence of predecessors. Let me know what you think. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @RettHamin Great! I've un-downvoted and voted to reopen.

Comment: Rett Hamin : the way you've written that "every element has an immediate successor" is incorrect. Think about it this way : if $x$ is a maximal element of a linear ordering, then what can you say about the formula "$\exists y,  \forall z (x< z \implies (y< z \land x < y))$" ? There's the same issue with how you have written that every element has an immediate predecessor. (I have taken the liberty of changing $\leq$ to $<$, otherwise both formulas you wrote are true of every orderin

Comment: Moreover, the last sentence "This is undecidable because..." needs more proof : how do you know that there does not exist a proof ? More generally, how do you show that a formula is independent of a given theory ?

Comment: @Max I first thought the sentence for immediate successor should be 
∀x ∃y ∀z (x < z iff (y ≤ z).
But then, I thought this doesn't specify that x < y < z and it could be that
y < x < z. However, It is because of the minimality of x, and this causes y > x. In your comment did you mean to say " if x is a minmal element?"

Comment: @Max I also thought of the following sentence for the immediate successor axiom:   
∀x ∃y (x < y ∧ ∀z (x ≤ z ≤ y → (x = z ∨ z = y).

Comment: @Max The last sentence is really the main thing I needed help with for this question. I am not sure how to show there doesn't exist a proof. If there existed a proof it seems that would be easy, because then I could just give the proof of the sentence using the inference rules of the Natural Deduction System. But I don't know how to show there doesn't exist a proof using these inference rules.

Comment: No no I did mean maximal element. Your second comment's formula is correct, the point was that you needed to specify "$x<y$" before any implication etc. As for the last sentence, you must have had a class about peoving independence of statements. I can give you the answer if you want to, but until then, a hint : consider the theory of groups $T$ in the language $\{=, *, 1, ^{-1}\}$. Can you show that the formula $\forall x, \forall y, x*y = y*x$ is independent of $T$ ?

Comment: @Max I'm sorry, I'm afraid I don't know how to do this. I searched my lecture notes and text and can't find an example.

Comment: Ok I'll write you an answer to explain this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've already answered in the comments about how to express that every element has an immediate successor and I think you understood that so I won't linger on it here (unless you want me to)

For the second part, the idea is to use what some call the *correction theorem*, which is just a theorem that says that the way we do proofs is fine. It asserts "For any language $L$, theory $T$ and formula $\phi$, if $T\vdash \phi$, then any model $M$ of $T$ has $M\models \phi$". Intuitively it says that if you can prove something, then it's "always true".

Here since we want to show that $\Gamma$ does *not* prove a certain formula we want to use the contrapositive : if there is some model $M$ of $\Gamma$ such that $\neg(M\models \phi)$, then there is no proof of $\phi$ in $\Gamma$. Moreover if we also find a model $N$ of $\Gamma$ such that $N\models \phi$, we will have that there is no proof of $\neg \phi$ in $\Gamma$.

Thus what we want to do is find a formula $\phi$, and models of $\Gamma$ $M,N$ such that $M\models \phi$, and $N\models \neg \phi$. A model of $\Gamma$ is simply a totally ordered set in which any element has an immediate successor. What are the simplest ones ? I guess they are $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{Z}$ with the usual ordering. They are obviously not isomorphic (as ordered sets) since $\mathbb{N}$ is well-ordered and $\mathbb{Z}$ isn't.

This fact makes us think (unrightfully though because elementary equivalence and isomorphism are different concepts) that there ought to be some formula that holds in one and not the other.

Such a formula would be "every element has an immediate predecessor" (I'll let you write it down properly, it's a good exercise - I'll call it $\phi$), which holds in $\mathbb{Z}$ but not in $\mathbb{N}$ ($0$ doesn't have any predecessor).

So we have found a formula $\phi$ such that $\mathbb{Z}\models \phi$, $\mathbb{N}\models \neg\phi$.  Therefore, from what I've shown earlier, there is no proof in $\Gamma$ of $\phi$, or $\neg\phi$: $\phi$ is undecidable in $\Gamma$

Comment: I guess a slightly simpler example would be a formula saying that "there is a least element".

Comment: You're right. I don't know why I looked for something so complicated

Comment: @Max Sorry I am just now getting back to you. Thank you very much for your help. This makes sense now. My professor has actually now done some problems very similar to this. He took this route: Γ doesn't prove ϕ, is equivalent to Γ, ¬ϕ being consistent, and Γ doesn't prove ¬ϕ, is equivalent to Γ, ϕ being consistent. Then by the completeness theorem Γ, ¬ϕ being consistent is equivalent to ∃ a model M s.t. M satisfies Γ, ¬ϕ, and  Γ, ϕ being consistent is equivalent to ∃ a model N s.t. N satisfies Γ, ϕ. This is basically the exact same thing that you did.

Comment: Yes this is essentially the same. I'm glad it makes sense to you !